# Emailing From a MS Access Database without the need of Outlook

Tags: email, ms-access, outlook

Is there way send an email from Access without using Outlook. I know of the 
`DoCmd.SendObject` method where you set one of the parameters to 'email' and it will use outlook to send the email, but this database is going to be used on the working floor where the employees all use a labor account with computers that don't have outlook installed on them. Is there another option?

Comment: DoCmd.sendObject does not use Outlook, but your default email software ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See Tony Toews' [Microsoft Access Email FAQ](http://www.granite.ab.ca/access/email.htm) for several alternatives.